# C# Linq -Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq

How to use extension methods to form the second query as the first one.

```
1) var query = from cm in cust
               group cm by cm.Customer into cmr
               select (new { CKey = cmr.Key, Count = cmr.Count() });
```

**(second query is not well formed)**

```
2)    var qry = cust.GroupBy(p => p.Customer).
                Select(new { CKey = p.Key, Count = p.Count });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
var query = cust.GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
                .Select(g => new { CKey = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

You can also simplify this into a single call to [this `GroupBy` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) though:

```
var query = cust.GroupBy(p => p.Customer,
                         (key, g) => new { CKey = key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Note that I've changed the name of the lambda expression's parameter name for the second line to `g` - I believe that gives more of a clue that you're really looking at a group rather than a single entity.

I've also moved the dot onto the second line in the form that still uses `Select` - I find this makes the query easier to read; I usually line up the dots, e.g.

```
var query = foo.Where(...)
               .OrderBy(...)
               .GroupBy(...)
               .Select(...)
```

Comment: Jon,You mean to say the  order could be where...OrderBy...GroupBy..,right?

Comment: He means to say that separate all the tags like .where . select into separate lines so that its easy to read :)

Comment: Mahesh is right - those were just sample methods. They could have been entirely different ones.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need:

```
var qry = cust.GroupBy(p => p.Customer)
    .Select(grp => new { CKey = grp.Key, Count = grp.Count() });
```